# How to trigger "inline suggestion" in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

There're two built-in commands for showing "inline suggestion":

- `editor.action.inlineSuggest.showPrevious`
- `editor.action.inlineSuggest.showNext`

I've tried both, but nothing happened, in what circumstance could an inline suggestion be triggered?

Comment: There is also `editor.action.inlineSuggest.trigger` but in my testing I can't get it to work in Stable or Insiders.   Make sure you have `Editor > Inline Suggest: Enabled` enabled, but it just doesn't work for me in Stable.  In the Insiders, I can get the inline suggestions to show up, but your commands you asked about do nothing.  So these new commands and the `inlineSuggestions` functionality are not ready IMO.

Comment: The answer here is for extensions, but as of v1.66 this can be enabled for users.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_66.md#quick-suggestions-as-inline-completions and https://stackoverflow.com/a/71622262/836330

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For v1.58+, see [Inline Suggestions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_58.md#inline-suggestions):

> #### Inline Suggestions
>
> The inline suggestions API allows extensions to provide inline suggestions that are decoupled from the suggestion widget. An inline suggestion is rendered as if it was already accepted, but with a gray color. Users can cycle through suggestions and accept them with the `Tab` key.
>
> ```
> vscode.languages.registerInlineCompletionItemProvider(
>   { pattern: '**' },
>   {
>     provideInlineCompletionItems: async (document, position) => {
>       return [{ text: '< 2) {\n\treturn 1;\n\t}' }]
>     },
>   },
> )
> ```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: the part of the gif that actually shows what to type is super short. mind adding the text as actual text?

Answer (score 3):

VS Code now allows you to choose how you'd like to code suggestions to appear.

By default, they appear in a *widget*, but you can also choose them to appear *in-line* as you write.

If you want the code suggestions to be shown *in-line*, then go to **Settings** by pressing down **CTRL + , (comma)** and type in **quick suggestions**.

Edit the item labeled *other* and select the *inline* value.

[image]

The in-line code suggestion looks like this:

[image]

[Source](https://neutrondev.com/vs-code-inline-suggestions/)

Answer (score 0):

The default keyboard shortcuts of `editor.action.inlineSuggest.showNext` and `editor.action.inlineSuggest.showPrevious` have when clauses like `inlineSuggestionVisible && !editorReadonly` (very reasonably / as they should). So if you're not seeing inline suggestions, maybe you didn't set it up right. Check the sub-properties of your `editor.quickSuggestions` setting and make sure you have set to `"inline"` those that you want to get inline suggestions for. The setting can also be overridden on a per-language basis (Ex. `"[cpp]": { "editor.quickSuggestions": { ... } }`), so make sure you check your overrides too if you have any.

If the problem is that the inline suggestion showed up but you did something to close it (Ex. pressing <kbd>esc</kbd>), then you can reopen it by using the `Trigger Inline Suggestion` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), which isn't bound to a keyboard shortcut by default, but you can bind using the command ID `editor.action.inlineSuggest.trigger`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "extension.command1",
            "title": "My Inline Completion Demo Settings"
        }
    ],
    "keybindings": [
        {
            "key": "ctrl+p",
            "command": "extension.command1",
            "mac": "ctrl+p"
        },
        {
            "key": "ctrl+o",
            "command": "editor.action.inlineSuggest.trigger",
            "mac": "ctrl+o"
        }

    ]
},
```

Comment: why would one write an extension just to add a keybinding to a builtin VS Code command?