# Monaco: How to add inline autocomplete/code suggestion?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

I couldn't find any examples on how to add inline autocomplete like the images below? Can someone guide me on how to do this in monaco?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that even possible? I haven't seen this feature in Monaco itself or vscode. Can you point me to a resource that demonstrates it?

Comment: @MikeLischke Hey Mike, after a lot of digging I found this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/inline-completions

Comment: Interesting, but seems only be available in the insiders build currently. So, not many people have tried it out yet, I guess. Also, the animation shows something different than what you want here, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be enabled in v1.66 (it is in the Insiders now):

> The `editor.quickSuggestions` setting now accepts inline as
> configuration value. When set to inline, quick suggestions
> (IntelliSense) don't display the suggestions widget when you type but
> show completions as ghosted text.

See [v1.66 release notes: inline quick suggestions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_66.md#quick-suggestions-as-inline-completions)

In your settings:

```
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": "inline", // the `inline` value is new
    "comments": true,
    "strings": true
  }
```

With this setting the suggestions will appear **inline** rather than as a pop-up.

[image: getting the suggestions inline]